# MongoDB get a count from array by day

Tags: mongodb

I have a (simplified) Json document in the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c29904e4b039512fc268b1"),
    "type" : "build",
    "time" : ISODate("2015-01-23T18:54:45.378Z"),
    "data" : {
            "buildNumber" : 228,
            "buildResult" : "FAILURE",
            "committers" : [
                    {
                            "name" : "Mike Smith"
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

For all documents with a FAILURE status in data.buildResult I'd like to get a count of how many times a committer has committed code resulting in a failed build in a given month.  For example I'd like to see something like the following:

```
Feb - Mike Smith - 20
Feb - Jane Smith - 15
Feb - John Doe   -  5
Mar - Mike Smith - 10
```

The query I have is below:

```
db.builds.aggregate([
    { $match: { "data.buildResult": "FAILURE", "data.committers.name" : { $exists : true }  } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            month: { $month: "$time" },
            name: "$data.committers.name", 
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } },

    { $sort: { "count": 1} }
])
```

This is returning results like the following:

```
{ "_id" : { "month" : 1, "name" : [ "Mike Smith" ] }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "month" : 1, "name" : [ "Mike Smith", "Jane Smith" ] }, "count" : 3 }
```

Not quite what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `committers` array into separate docs so that they're counted separately in the `$group`:

```javascript
db.builds.aggregate([
    { $match: { "data.buildResult": "FAILURE", "data.committers.name": { $exists: true } } },
    { $unwind: '$data.committers' },
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            month: { $month: "$time" },
            name: "$data.committers.name", 
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } },
    { $sort: { "count": 1} }
])
```

Which gives output like:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 1,
        "name" : "Jane Smith"
    },
    "count" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 1,
        "name" : "Mike Smith"
    },
    "count" : 1
}
```